# How to provide parameter in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I have below shell script where i want to create another parameter and instead of `in` in the line `$JAVA_BIN $JAVA_OPTS --workflow test_method --config config/dbimport.$1.properties in` i want to provide that parameter.

```
 #!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "usage: test_method_full.sh <env> ; whereas env is one of dev|simu|prod"
    exit 1
fi

# ******************** Check arguments **********
if [[ $1 != "dev" && $1 != "simu" && $1 != "prod" ]]; then
    echo "env parameter has to be dev, simu or prod. Found ${1}"
    exit 3
fi


# ***************** Java-Environment **************

# use given JAVA_HOME or openjava-1.8  if available
if [[ -z ${JAVA_HOME} ]]; then
    # JAVA_HOME does not exist
    if [[ -d /opt/java-1.8  ]]; then
        JAVA_HOME=/opt/java-1.8
    else
        echo "JAVA_HOME could not be determined!"
        exit 5
    fi
fi

# set the Java binary based on JAVA_HOME
JAVA_BIN=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java


$JAVA_BIN $JAVA_OPTS -classpath "/opt/Software/lib/*:/opt/Software/test_method/lib/*" --workflow test_method --config config/dbimport.$1.properties in
```

While running the script it should run like below:

```
    test_method_full.sh simu /opt/Software/in
```

I dont want to hardcode `/opt/Software/in/` in my shell script and make it changeable while runnig the script

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. There's no line  `$JAVA_BIN [etc]`. Is the script called `test_method_full.sh` or is that what you want to call? Please update your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have updated question..actually i just want to put small part of the script...yes the script is called test_method_full.sh...i want to run the script for example like test_method_full.sh simu /opt/localsoftware/in  with two parameter...the second parameter i dont want to hardcode in my script as it can be changed

Comment: The second argument is just `$2` - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: instead of in if i just give  $2 does it work ?

Comment: @l0b0 yes exactly so if i just give $2 instead of in and run the script with two paramter does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to pass it as optional parameter (i.e. `"${2:-/opt/Software/in/}"`), which can override the default, but uses the default, if you don't pass a parameter, or use an environment variable for it, say: `"${JAVA_ARG:-/opt/Software/in/}"`, in a similar way you are already doing it for `JAVA_OPTS`.

Comment: actually i dont want to hardcode /opt/Software/in/ in my shell script and make it changeable while runnig the script..so if i just give $2 instead of in and run the script with two paramter does it work?

Comment: You don't have to. But not having default values means that the user is forced to supply the argument explicitly on every run. In this case, you might want to fetch the paramter by `${2?:2nd argument missing}`. If the caller forgets to supply a parameter, this will abort the script with an understandable error message.